# Crypress drag/drop of element fromm outside iframe to inside

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, cypress

I'm starting write tests, and we integrate an iframe in our product and the drag/drop is working manually, but the implementation of test using Cypress encounter problem.
Element (outside cypress) is correctly detected, but on dropping it in a iframe doesn't work.
I've done a lot of try with drag/drop or mousedown/mousemove/mouseup but cannot obtain any results.
Is somebody used has encountered the problem and how it has been solved.

Thanks